# Display ModX placeholders as code in ModX resource?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want to share some ModX template code I've made on my ModX site. I can paste the html in fine using `<pre>` but the chunks, eg `[[$footer]]` `[[$header]]` and placeholders, eg `[[*content]]` still display as ModX Placeholders meaning I see the contents of `[[$header]]` rather than just the code.

Does anyone know I way I can display placeholder and chunk code/hooks within a ModX resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution mentioned by okiyanet in more detail. Create a snippet `convertModxTags` and place this code inside:

```
<?php
$output = str_replace('[[','&#91;&#91;',$input);
return $output;
```

Then call it in your template:

```
[[!convertModxTags?&input=`[[*content]]`]]
```

or

```
[[*content:convertModxTags]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could swap out the brackets with the relevant HTML codes to prevent them being parsed by MODX.

- `[[` becomes `&#91;&#91;`
- `]]` becomes `&#93;&#93;`

If you need to do this regularly you might look at writing a plugin to do this for you, perhaps running a string replace whenever you save your resources.

Answer (score 1):

There are two extras that will do this for you:

The [FixedPre](http://bobsguides.com/fixedpre-tutorial.html) plugin will show both MODX and HTML tags inside of fixedpre tags.

The [SyntaxHighlighter](http://bobsguides.com/syntaxhighlighter-tutorial.html) plugin or snippet will do the same, but will also highlight the code and put it in a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin for Revo:
http://www.modx360.com/blog/2010/02/12/prevent-parsing-modx-tags/

Create it as an PlugIn, do not forget to tip on:
OnLoadWebDocument
OnWebPagePrerender
OnBeforeSaveWebPageCache

And paste your REVO-MODX-code on your page between two code-elements.